# How to avoid to read the inserted ID in Eclipselink JPA

Tags: sql-server, database, jpa, eclipselink

I'm running a process that makes lot's of inserts, but can't be done in a bulk way. It is inserting one by one (in an isolated transaction).

After each insert, JPA executes the ''SELECT @@IDENTITY'' sentence, and I don't care to get the id to store it in the persistence context (as a matter of fact, I'm no interested in getting the new inserted object in the p. context).

How can I avoid that JPA executes that query?

I know that I can create a native query with the insert, but I prefer a JPA way.

I'm using SQL Server 2014

Comment: Use a different generation strategy (since your choice is to have it assigned in the datastore, hence it needs to get hold of it after), or use SQL INSERT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know is the native insert statement

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. JPA needs the ID after the insert.